# Why doesn't greasemonkey make this GM_xmlhttpRequest?

Tags: ajax, greasemonkey

According to http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest, somthing like this script should work:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           test
// @namespace      _test
// @include        http://stackoverflow.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

alert("_hello world_");

GM_xmlhttpRequest({
  method: "GET",
  url: "http://www.flickr.com/",
  onload: function(response) {
    alert("success");
  },
  onerror: function(response) {
      alert(
          [
            response.status,
            response.statusText,
          ].join("\n"));
  }
});
```

When I try it, I get the "*hello world*", but the GM_xmlhttpRequest seems to fail silently.

Why doesn't the `onload`or the `onerror` execute?

I use Firefox 4.0, Greasemonkey 0.9.1. (A combination that seems very prone to crash).

Comment: Yes, it seems the FF 4.0, GM 0.9.1, and Firebug 1.7.0 are a tad flaky at the moment.  Hopefully, there will be some updates in the next few days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug, please report to http://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues

Comment: what is the number of the ticket? Can 't seem to find it and like to watch it, as it just hit me too i fear

Answer (score 0):

Might be an issue in upstream; opened a new tab and the issue disappeared. Please follow: https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues/1318 and https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=647727